# Konvajs component loads but canvas doesn't

Tags: javascript, vue.js, konvajs

Hey guys I have the following component its pretty simple just the load video demo code on the konva js website. The problem I am having is when I load this component in vue it works the first time but if I load it on another component the canvas does not show up.

Canvas component

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <div id="canvas-container">
              <button id="play">Play</button><button id="pause">Pause</button>
               <div id="container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
mounted: async function(){
      console.log("I mounted canvas");
      var width = 1280;
      var height = 720;

      var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height,
      });

      var layer = new Konva.Layer();
      stage.add(layer);

      var video = document.createElement('video');
      video.src =
        `/api/files/stock/1080/downloadable/1080.mp4`;

      var image = new Konva.Image({
        image: video,
        draggable: true,
        x: 50,
        y: 20,
      });
      layer.add(image);

      var text = new Konva.Text({
        text: 'Loading video...',
        width: stage.width(),
        height: stage.height(),
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
      });
      layer.add(text);

      layer.draw();

      var anim = new Konva.Animation(function () {
        // do nothing, animation just need to update the layer
        console.log("animation called");
      }, layer);

      // update Konva.Image size when meta is loaded
      video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function (e) {
        text.text('Press PLAY...');
        image.width(video.videoWidth);
        image.height(video.videoHeight);
      });

      document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function () {
        text.destroy();
        video.play();
        anim.start();
      });
      document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', function () {
        video.pause();
        anim.stop();
      });
    }

}
</script>
<style scoped>
#canvas-container{ 
   max-height: 75vh;
   max-width: 67vw;
  overflow: auto;
  }
</style>
```

Than I include that code in the following components
Pallett Step

```
<template>
  <div class="palette-step">
    <div v-if="!selectColors">
      <template v-if="!currentVideo.json">
      <thumbnail/>
      </template>
      <template v-else>
        <p>Holy crap</p>
        <canvas-view/>
       </template>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

And Text step

```
<template>
  <div class="text-step">
    <template v-if="this.currentVideo.json && this.dataClay.matrix[0]">
      <canvas-view/>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <thumbnail/>
    </template>
```

I call these components like so:

```
<template>
  <div class="wizard">
    <component :is="component"/>
    <controls/>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import FileStep from "./Steps/FileStep.vue";
import TextStep from "./Steps/TextStep.vue";
import ImageStep from "./Steps/ImageStep.vue";
import PaletteStep from "./Steps/PaletteStep.vue";
import SubmitStep from "./Steps/SubmitStep.vue";
import Controls from "./Controls.vue";
import SignupStep from "./Steps/SignupStep.vue";


import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  components: {
    PaletteStep,
    FileStep,
    TextStep,
    ImageStep,
    SubmitStep,
    Controls,
    SignupStep,
    CanvasView
  },
  props: ["type"],
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["currentStepDetails"]),
    component() {
      if (this.type) {
        return this.type + "-step";
      }
    },
    kioskMode() {
      return process.env.VUE_APP_KIOSK_MODE === "offline";
    }
  }
  // Add error in case one of the steps fails to load
};
</script>

<style>
.wizard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .wizard {
    margin-top: -15px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .wizard {
    max-width: 750px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .wizard {
    max-width: 750px;
  }
}
.instructions {
  width: 100%;
  font-style: italic;
}
</style>
```

the first time I run the project it loads
[image]

But if I go forward and go back or just go forward it does not load. Yet the component is there and the mounted function with my code runs. The canvas does not show up. I also know my if condition is working due to Holy Crap showing up.
[image]
[image]

As you can see there's no Konva content div when it doesn't load. Why is this? If I navigate to step (component) that does not use the canvas-view component and then go back it works. But if I go from one contains canvas-view to another with canvas-view it won't show up.

Comment: Can you make a small demo? Try to use different keys for canvas components. It may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough it had to do with my `<transition-group>` when I got rid of the transition group it worked perfectly. Not exactly sure as to why.